# SharePoint User Code Host Eating all my memory and CPU

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running **sharepoint 2013** on a w**indows server R2 2012,** my machine has **12gb RAM**. The problem is that above process is **creating multiple instances** which are in turn eating all my ram and CPU.

See below 
[image]

I'm running one web application on a single server.

See my system properties
[image]

Any idea on how to solve that guys?

Comment: Generally, 12GB of RAM is not enough to run SP 2013 with all services

Comment: But creating infinite number of instances seems abnormal to me?

Comment: could you please provide below details - How many Web applications: - Your Environment architect - How much core your server having

Comment: see the updates

Comment: As I see You are having 2cores in single server farm. Please increase to 4cores to minimize your process. Also check worker process in IIS to get more reed to it.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of TaskManager which shows the full names of the processes which eat up your RAM? Maybe also a screenshot from the "details" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sandbox Solutions you need the User Code Service to make them work. If you don't then turn it off. That service, along with the associated host controller, creates a new process for each instance of your sandbox solution. The more solutions you deploy, the more RAM you will need.

Generally, on a development box, with Visual Studio, you would want 16-24 GB RAM.

If you spin up the Search Service it will spin up 6 processes that will eat your RAM. Again, if you don't need search in development, don't create the service application. If you do, dial down the performance level so you are not impacted.

Comment: Thank you I have turned off sandbox solutions and it worked like charm!!

Comment: Great! Watch out for the Search process on your server. You don't have the resources. :)